# Google Sheets: one query for Sum and Filter?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-filter

If I have a sheet with data like this:

```
A    B
x    1
y    2
z    3
x    4
```

I can sum the values with

```
=query(A:B, "select A, sum(B) group by A")
```

How can I then filter this result? For example, in SQL to see x and y only (excluding z), I would add a WHERE clause like:

```
WHERE A IN ('x', 'y')
```

How can I get this functionality in a Sheets query?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`=query(A:B, "select A, sum(B)  where A is not null and A <> 'z' group by A")`